# Multiple selection issue in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

May be a simple issue, but i cant find a way around. I need to do a multiple selection in a listbox and save all its value. But somehow I am only getting the last selected one. Any way to get all the selections and save it into a dictionary or something like that ?

```
def save_user_doc():
    selected_data = {}
    selected_column = user_doc_listbox.get(user_doc_listbox.curselection())
    
    if selected_column:
        selected_indices = []  # Initialize an empty list for selected indices


        for idx in selected_column_values.curselection():
            selected_indices.append(idx)  # Append each selected index to the list
            print('selected indices', selected_indices) 


        # Retrieve selected values using list comprehension
        selected_values = [selected_column_values.get(idx) for idx in selected_indices]
        
        # Ensure selected values are not empty
        if selected_values:
            # If the selected column already exists in selected_data, extend its values
            if selected_column in selected_data:
                selected_data[selected_column].extend(selected_values)
            else:
                # Otherwise, create a new entry for the column
                selected_data[selected_column] = selected_values

            # Find the maximum length of all value lists
            max_len = max(len(values) for values in selected_data.values())
            
            # Pad shorter lists with None to ensure equal length
            for col, values in selected_data.items():
                selected_data[col] += [None] * (max_len - len(values))
            
            # Create custom index with the appropriate length
            custom_index = range(1, max_len + 1)
            
            # Create DataFrame from selected data
            selected_df = pd.DataFrame(selected_data, index=custom_index)
            
            # Prompt user to select file path and save DataFrame to Excel file
            save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
            if save_path:
                selected_df.to_excel(save_path, index=True)
                print("Selections saved to:", save_path)
        else:
            print("Please select values from the second listbox.")
    else:
        print("Please select a column from the first listbox.")
```

I need to find a solution to get all values while doing a multiple selection using tkinter

Comment: Please create a minimal but complete example. There's a lot of code missing from your example, and also a fair amount of code that doesn't seem necessary to reproduce the problem. Your code seems to have more than one listbox so it's hard to know which one you're asking about.

Comment: I think you need to move the line `selected_data = {}` to outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code is required. I guess the problem could be the following. While defining `listbox`, It is required to be mentioned that `selectmode='multiple'`.

```
listbox = Listbox(tab3, selectmode = "multiple")
```